# Tensorflow: how to subtract 2 tensors in a 'Cartesian product' way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I want to do something like this:

```
v = tf.get_variable('v', [N])
p = tf.placeholder(shape=[None])
tmp = []
for element_p in p:
   tmp.append(element_p - v)
ret = tf.stack(tmp, axis=0)
# ret.get_shape().as_list() = [None, N]
```

Is this possible in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making use of broadcasting:

```
import tensorflow as tf

N = ...
v = tf.get_variable('v', [N])
p = tf.placeholder(shape=[None])
ret = p[:, tf.newaxis] - v[tf.newaxis, :]
```